# xcode 4.5 conversion issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I JUST finished my first app in Xcode 4.3.2 and want to test it on my iPhone which I (unfortunately) updated to OS 6 without thinking about the fact that I'd probably have to be using Xcode 4.5. So I downloaded the the 4.5 and tried to open my project in it, and I get the following error message all of a sudden:

apple mach-o Linker Error
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

My app was running JUST FINE in 4.3.2. I did not touch anything, I only opened the app in the new version and now I get a build failed with the above error. Can anyone help!? this is so frustrating! My app has Facebook integrated into it, so maybe that is related? I have no idea... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its probably related to some framework missing or incompatible. Can you post whole error log ? or screenshot ?

Comment: the full error was: ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/jac300/Desktop/FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.framework/FacebookSDK for architecture armv7s

Comment: May be when you converted project, you have switched to armv7 only. Try checking supported architecture in project setting and set it to both armv6 and armv7

Comment: thank you! it was a compatability issue. updated to fb sdk 3.1 and all is well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm maybe you could try to see if the Facebook framework is added..